# Prove that $\{C_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a chain complex with boundary homomorphism $\partial:=\bigoplus_{\alpha\in\Lambda}\partial^{\alpha} $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

**Let $\Lambda $ be a fixed set. For each $\alpha\in\Lambda $ is $\{C_n^{\alpha}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ a chain complex with boundary homomorphism $\partial^{\alpha}$.**

**For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we define $C_n=\bigoplus_{\alpha\in\Lambda}C_n^{\alpha} $. Prove that $\{C_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a chain complex with boundary homomorphism $\partial:=\bigoplus_{\alpha\in\Lambda}\partial^{\alpha} $.**

To show that $\{C_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a chain complex with boundary homomorphism  $\partial$, we have to prove that $\partial\circ\partial=0$. For this, let's take $(x_{\alpha})\in C_n$ so $(\partial\circ\partial)(x_{\alpha})=\partial(\partial(x_{\alpha}))=\partial((\partial^{\alpha}(x_{\alpha})))=(\partial^{\alpha}(\partial^{\alpha}(x_{\alpha})))=((\partial^{\alpha}\circ\partial^{\alpha})(x_{\alpha}))=(0)$. Is this demonstration okay? What can be improved? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: That's fine. If you know that direct sum is a functor, then there's no need to introduce $(x_\alpha)$. You can just say $\partial\circ\partial = (\partial_\alpha \circ \partial_\alpha) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, your proof is correct.